# Universal Windows Applications using ReactiveUI package fail to build in Release mode

Tags: uwp, reactiveui, release-mode

Universal Windows Application fails to build in Release with ReactiveUI

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Create a blank Universal Windows Application.
2. Add the ReactiveUI package (latest version 10.1.6)
3. Change the configuration to Release
4. Change the platform to x86 or x64.
5. Build the application.
6. You should get an error like this:

> error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.7-rel-27913-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\JMN\source\repos\App6\App6\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\App6.rsp"' returned exit code 1

**Expected behavior**

Build successful

**Environment**

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Version   18362.356
- Device:   Windows Desktop

**Additional context**

Targeting:
Target version: Windows 10 v1903. Minimum version: Windows 10 v1809

Comment: I suppose  you have refer some nuget package that not support release mode.

Comment: Please check which platform will give the error fist. Then remove the NuGet packages one by one to find out which one is the cause.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've edited the OP. I've dug into the issue and it's related to ReactiveUI.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It's already there.https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2166

Comment: @nico Zhu we encourage users to post to stack overflow. Noticed you offer that advice a few times and it's not a exclusive msft advice forum.